# How to check rows for continuity?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have an operation that if it fails - it retries 5 times and then gives up.  Resulting in following log table:

```
LogId   OpId  Message
1       4     Retry 1...Failed
2       4     Retry 2...Failed
3       4     Retry 3...Failed
4       4     Retry 4...Failed
5       4     Retry 5...Failed
6       4     Max Retries exceeded - giving up
```

Sometimes, it will succeed after retry, which means that I'll never see the `Max Retries exceeded - giving up` entry within that OpId.

And that I what I am trying to identify.  Operations that were forced to go into retries (e.g there is a `Retry X...` entry), but there isn't a `Max Retries exceeded - giving up` entry because the retry succeeded at some point.

I tried using Window functions, and I think that might the way to go but I am not sure how to actually identify what I want.

P.S. Added auto-incrementing field per @GMB

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect.

Comment: You might need a column in the table that can be used to *sort* the records, like an incrementing id or a timestamp. Otherwise, we cannot tell which records goes *after* the other.

Comment: @GMB You are right.  There are timestamp and identity fields.  I just didn't include it in the dataset.  I'll add it the identity field to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this dataset, you might be able to just use aggregation:

```
select opId
from mytable
group by opId
having 
    max(case when message like 'Retry%' then 1 end) = 1
    and max(case when message = 'Max Retries exceeded - giving up' then 1 end) is null
```

This gives you the list of `opId` for which at least one message starts with `'Retry'` and that have no message equal to `'Max Retries exceeded - giving up'`.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that goes into retries will have a "Retry 1...Failed" entry, so (assuming opid is different for each set) a self join would probably work.

```
SELECT opId
   , CASE WHEN tGU.opId IS NULL THEN 'Eventually Succeeded' ELSE 'Gave Up' END AS final
FROM theTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN theTable AS tGU 
   ON t1.opId = tGU.opId 
   AND tGU.Message = "Max Retries exceeded - giving up"
WHERE t1.Message = "Retry 1...Failed"
```

If you just want ops that eventually succeeded, you can omit the CASE WHEN stuff (I really just meant it as an example), and just and `AND tGU.opId IS NULL` to the WHERE clause.

However, and I don't think there is really a way around this, ops currently retrying will be considered "eventually successful". (Due to the nature of the data, you cannot really know "eventually succeeded"; only "didn't or hasn't yet given up".)

Also, perhaps it is a wording thing, but what if "Retry 1" succeeds? (Or does "Retry 1...Failed" really intend to mean something like "Attempt 1 failed, retrying"?)

Answer (score 1):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=307881806d4da72e5f37c080e419e00b

Given a table that looks something like

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.so_60047052(OpId int, Message varchar(50));

insert into dbo.so_60047052
SELECT * 
FROM
(
VALUES
    (4,'Retry 1...Failed')
,   (4,'Retry 2...Failed')
,   (4,'Retry 3...Failed')
,   (4,'Retry 4...Failed')
,   (4,'Retry 5...Failed')
,   (4,'Max Retries exceeded - giving up')
-- Some failure but not all
,   (5,'Retry 1...Failed')
,   (6,'Retry 1...Failed')
,   (6,'Retry 2...Failed')

,   (8,'Retry 1...Failed')
,   (8,'Retry 2...Failed')
,   (8,'Retry 3...Failed')
,   (8,'Retry 4...Failed')
)D(OpId, Message);
```

You can attack it a few different ways

```
-- Show me anything that got into a terminal status
SELECT 
    D.OpId
,   D.Message
FROm
    dbo.so_60047052 AS D
WHERE
    D.Message = 'Max Retries exceeded - giving up';

-- Show me the "last" failing message where it didn't hit max retries
-- Last is in quotes as it's only last because the text sorts that way    
SELECT 
    D.OpId
,   D.Message
FROM
    dbo.so_60047052 AS D
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.so_60047052 AS DI 
    WHERE DI.Message = 'Max Retries exceeded - giving up'
    AND DI.OpId = D.OpId
    )
    AND D.Message = 
    (
    SELECT MAX(DI.Message)
    FROM dbo.so_60047052 AS DI 
    WHERE 
     DI.OpId = D.OpId
    );
```

If you have a table that records all the OpId, beyond the ones that have trouble, you can then build out a set that "had no issues", "had transient issues", "failed" based on